# next.js - How to specify a port to run start slicemachine app on

Tags: next.js, port, prismic.io

I am new to prismic, I just started learning about it last week and how to use it with Next.js projects. I decided to clone the `Blog start` project of prismic. So I found myself in a situation where I want to have 2 slice machines working simultaneously on different ports. Does someone know how to manually specify the port number on which the slice machine will run?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run it on port 5000 you run `npm run slicemachine -- --port 5000`

If you're using yarn run `yarn run slicemachine --port 5000`